# How to Iterate Over AJAX Call and Push to Array

Tags: arrays, ajax, polymer-2.x

In this code I:

1. Get a list of items (via AJAX)
2. Get more items details (via 2nd AJAX call)
3. Push item + details to history array

Code:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[history]]" index-as="index">
  <p>[[item.itemId]]>
  <p>[[item.priceNet]]</p>
</template>
```

...

```
getRequest() {
  let request = this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
  request.completes.then(req => {
      // returns this.data;
      this.i = 0;
      console.log(this.history); // Logs several objects in array on 1st iteration
      this.getRequest2();
    })
}

getRequest2() {
  if (this.i<this.data.length) {
      this.itemId = this.data[this.i].itemId;
      let request = this.$.ajax2.generateRequest();
      request.completes.then(req => {
        this.updateHistory();
      })
    }
  }

updateHistory() {
  if(typeof this.responseStock.error == 'undefined') {
    this.push('history', {
      "itemId": this.response[0][this.i].itemId,
      "priceNet": this.responseStock.priceNet
    })
  } else {
    this.push('history', {
      "itemId": this.response[0][this.i].itemId,
      "priceNet": null
    })
  }
  this.i = this.i + 1;
  this.getRequest2();
}
```

However, upon the first instance history logs multiple objects in the array, so the `push` method doesn't properly update.

**How can I pass the data through so that each item that gets returned from the 1st AJAX call gets attributed with the 2nd AJAX call if attributes exist, and then push it to an array?**

Note: the `this.push` is from the Polymer framework, but the problem seems to be that the timing of the `push` method is off...

Comment: You're using `req => {}` functions but then not doing anything with the `req` object that has all your data in it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I've updated the question to reflect the template binding.

Comment: Look at `request.completes.then(req => { ... })` You're not doing anything with the `req` object, just calling some other function in the body of your callback without passing it the `req` object.  It's the `req` object that has all your data in it.